# Can't require php files from another folder - permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, stream, require, permission-denied

I have a web server where i host **script1** in `/home/srcipt1/` and **script2** is in `/home/script2`

When i try to include a file from **script2** folder into **script1** i get permission errors

```
Warning: require_once(/home/script1/public_html/SSI.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/script2/public_html/q3/config/config.php on line 32
```

**EDIT:**

SSI.php has 755 permissions and /home/script2/public_html has 750 permissions

Comment: You need to make sure that the user that your webserver is running as, has read permission on that folder and the files in there.

Comment: The problem may be that you're trying to access files outside the `public_html` folder. Try moving your scripts inside it, it should work, e.g.: `/home/public_html/script1/yourscript.php` and `/home/public_html/script2/yourscript.php` and change the require function consequently, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

You may not have group permissions on that file. You could try this in your SSH shell:

```
chmod /home/script1/public_html/SSI.php 774
```

Make sure that you are using the correct ACL, 774 is group/user writable, readable and executable and world readable only.

Comment: what do you mean by ACL?

Comment: Access control, or permissions. If a file is set with incorrect permissions it will deny access to other files and users. If you are using an FTP client you usually can right click the file and set the permissions that way, too.

Comment: I have updated the question with the permissions of file and folder.

Comment: Right, try changing the SSI.php file's permissions to 774 instead of what it is now. Then run your script again.